# Convolution integral and its matrix representation

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

My background is chemistry and I was exploring some one dimensional deconvolution problems i.e., resolution of two or more overlapping peaks. A lot of excellent work was done in the 1970-80s. However, I wanted to clarify a conceptual point or proper mathematical nomenclature since most of these signal deconvolution problems are not written by mathematicians. Starting from convolution integral, the typical starting discussion is:

$$
C(E)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} W\left(E^{\prime}\right) R\left(E-E^{\prime}\right) \mathrm{d} E^{\prime}
$$
with
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} R(E) \mathrm{d} E=1
$$

where $E$ and $E^{\prime}$ denote the radiation energy; $C(E)$, $E(E)$ and $R(E)$ mean the observed spectrum, the intrinsic distribution and the response function, respectively. The goal is to obtain true distribution is obtained from deconvoluting the observed spectrum with the response function.

Most authors then switch to the following matrix equation,
$$
\mathrm{C}=R W
$$
where $R$ is a square matrix, and $C$ and $W$ are column vectors which correspond to the observed spectrum after background subtraction and to the intrinsic distribution, respectively.

(i) My understanding is that convolution by matrices is a *circular* convolution and this is done by circulant matrices. Is there a matrix formulation that is meant for linear convolution, or zero padding is the *only* way to obtain linear convolution out of circulant matrices? I mean is there a special matrix, besides circulant matrix, which performs linear convolution?

(ii) Sometimes the name Toepltiz matrix is used in deconvolution problems. Should we call $R$ a circulant matrix or a Toeplitz matrix?

I would appreciate a readible reference on this topic.

Comment: Any linear operation on a finite-dimensional based vector space is performed by a matrix.  But why do these signals live in a finite-dimensional space?

Comment: 1) a Toeplitz matrix (constant diagonals) can be used to represent a linear convolution, see for example these [notes](https://www.gaussianwaves.com/2014/02/polynomials-convolution-and-toeplitz-matrices-connecting-the-dots/); 2)  a circulant matrix is a special type of Toeplitz matrix; 3) don't know.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, Thanks for the useful link. In the notes they also zero padded the matrix to make it a linear convolution.

Comment: @LSpice, As to your point "But why do these signals live in a finite-dimensional space?" I think this is just a utilitarian approach. A real experiment has a starting time and an end time. Consider, collecting an infrared spectrum of water. A given infrared spectrometer will have a wavelength measurement range, again finite data.

Comment: In light of considering finite-dimensional signals, what do you mean by linear convolution?  It seems to me that this is nothing else *but* zero-padding.  That is, I don't know how to perform a linear convolution without regarding signals as extended by $0$ as necessary, and then the matrix implementing the convolution will have $0$s in the appropriate places.

Comment: Suppose the signal consisted of *N* points and the convolution function is also *N* points. When we do convolution /deconvolution by discrete Fourier transform, the output is also *N* points. if we use a *N*x*N* circulant matrix, the output would be a circular connvolution. By linear convolution, I implied that output  should have a length of 2N-1. I think zero padding is the *only* solution if we wish to obtain linear convolution from a Toeplitz matrix.

Comment: You can do any padding of W that is linear (zero padding, periodic padding, symmetric padding, repeating the boundary values,...) and will always get some matrix representation.